# free a pointer to struct

Tags: c, malloc, free

I have this code

```
 struct PDATA{
    int NTH;
    int NPH;
    double th_start;
    double th_step;
    double ph_start;
    double ph_step;
    };

    typedef struct PDATA *PDATA_P;

    struct PDATA PAT_DATA;
    PDATA_P PAT_DATA_P;

    PAT_DATA_P = (PDATA_P) malloc(sizeof(struct PDATA));
    PAT_DATA_P=&PAT_DATA;

    ....

    free(PAT_DATA_P);
```

When i free my pointer i obtain this error:

```
*** glibc detected *** /home/pc-linux/Desktop/Projects/AM_v0.1/Debug/AM_v0.1: free(): invalid pointer: 0xbfffe03c ***
```

Where the error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign the address of a variable allocated in stack to your pointer with the following line:

```
PAT_DATA_P=&PAT_DATA;
```

Then you try to free it!

Comment: I eliminated this line in my code and i used only reference to pointers and error has disappeared. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

your error is on the line `PAT_DATA_P = &PAT_DATA`

`PAT_DATA` is allocated on the stack.

Maybe you meant `*PAT_DATA_P = PAT_DATA` to copy the members, rather than assign the pointer?

Comment: Not to mention this leaks memory as you just lost your malloc with the assignment...

Comment: I would also recommend initializing the values of PAT_DATA before doing the copy (but, I assume that occurred in code that you cut out)

Answer (score 0):

Always initialize your variables to be created. It is a good practice.
PAT_DATA was not initialized at any time therefore can not be used.

Comment: while it is true that PAT_DATA wasn't initialized, that was not the cause of the error referred to by the user

Comment: When running PAT_DATA_P = & PAT_DATA the pointer to the previously allocated area is lost! How then using PAT_DATA is not the cause of the error?